# Consolidating Code into Loop

Tags: r

I have the following code in R and it accomplishes what I am trying to do but I need to make it more efficient in a loop so that I can run a simulation of say 10000 iterations of this test with sample data.

Use either data set since I have to do the test on both.

```
PerfectMate <- sample(1:20,20,replace = FALSE,prob = NULL)
date.mode <- PerfectMate[1:3]
marry.mode <- PerfectMate[4:20]

PerfectMate <- c(2,1,16,8,6,3,15,5,9,12,17,4,13,14,10,20,19,7,18,11)
date.mode <- PerfectMate[1:3]
marry.mode <- PerfectMate[4:20]

if (marry.mode[1] < min(date.mode)) {marry.rank <- marry.mode[1]} else {
 if (marry.mode[2] < min(date.mode)) {marry.rank <- marry.mode[2]} else {
  if (marry.mode[3] < min(date.mode)) {marry.rank <- marry.mode[3]} else {
   if (marry.mode[4] < min(date.mode)) {marry.rank <- marry.mode[4]} else {
    if (marry.mode[5] < min(date.mode)) {marry.rank <- marry.mode[5]} else {
      if (marry.mode[6] < min(date.mode)) {marry.rank <- marry.mode[6]} else {
        if (marry.mode[7] < min(date.mode)) {marry.rank <- marry.mode[7]} else {
          if (marry.mode[8] < min(date.mode)) {marry.rank <- marry.mode[8]} else {
            if (marry.mode[9] < min(date.mode)) {marry.rank <- marry.mode[9]} else {
              if (marry.mode[10] < min(date.mode)) {marry.rank <- marry.mode[10]} else {
                if (marry.mode[11] < min(date.mode)) {marry.rank <- marry.mode[11]} else {
                  if (marry.mode[12] < min(date.mode)) {marry.rank <- marry.mode[12]} else {
                    if (marry.mode[13] < min(date.mode)) {marry.rank <- marry.mode[13]} else {
                      if (marry.mode[14] < min(date.mode)) {marry.rank <- marry.mode[14]} else {
                        if (marry.mode[15] < min(date.mode)) {marry.rank <- marry.mode[15]} else {
                          if (marry.mode[16] < min(date.mode)) {marry.rank <- marry.mode[16]} else {
                            if (marry.mode[17] < min(date.mode)) {marry.rank <- marry.mode[17]} else {
                              marry.rank <- NA }
} } } } } } } } } } } } } } } }
marry.rank
```

Comment: Holy Conditional Batman! Are you trying to do `Find(function(x) x < min(date.mode), marry.mode)`?  Alternatively, `marry.mode[marry.mode < min(date.mode)][1]`

Comment: This looks like a work of art!

Comment: This looks like the mirror house at a circus, with two facing mirrors. Or the 17th level of [Inception](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1375666/).

Comment: It has nothing to do with calendar dates. I am trying to find the first value in the marry.mode vector that is less than the min(date.mode) and store that value as the vector named marry.rank. Then I want to run that loop for 10,000 iterations as a simulation using a sample data set each time. Then I am going to do some probability analysis on the results. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to do the following:

```
idxs <- which(marry.mode < min(date.mode))
marry.rank <- if (length(idxs) > 0) marry.mode[idxs[1]] else NA
```

Note: The answer was rewritten taking into account the suggestion in the comment by @r2evans (see below). Previously `ifelse` was used.

Comment: Using `ifelse` here is unnecessary and inefficient. I'd suggest as an alternative: `if (length(idxs) > 0) marry.mode[idxs[1]] else NA`. Functionally the same without some of the `ifelse` baggage.

Comment: @r2evans that works very well and efficiently, thank you. Now I need to put this into an equation that will perform the action when entering variables in x or n to change the vector length. Also I need to create a for loop that will run a simulation for 5000 iterations on the equation.

Comment: @r2evans Here is my code currently...choice_of_mate <- function(x,n) {
PerfectMate <- sample(1:x,x,replace = FALSE,prob = NULL)
date.mode <- PerfectMate[1:n]
marry.mode <- PerfectMate[n+1:x]
for (i in length(1:PerfectMate)) {
  marry.rank <- which(marry.mode < min(date.mode))
  marry.rank <- if (length(marry.rank) > 0) marry.mode[marry.rank[1]] else NA
}
marry.rank
}

choice_of_mate(20,3)

Comment: Please: (1) don't post code like that in comments; or (2) create a new question in comments. If this is not working for you, then please post the code, some sample/representative data, and your expected output into a new question.